# Orchard v.1.10 blog view permissions

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

How do i prevent anonymous user to view blog summery and posts?
I can set the edit blog permissions but can find a way to control the view permissions

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin content types select blog. check the checkbox "Securable",
Determines if this content type can have custom permissions.

To set custom permission for blog or other Content Type's.

Then under User settings go to Roles/Anonymous and you will have custom permissions for Blog and set them accordingly.
Uncheck Effective for, "View Blog by others".